# Adding new methods to an ADT

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `statistics.py` file which has some methods for the class Statistics. Here is how it looks:

```
class Statistics(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__count = 0      # how many data values seen so far
        self.__avg = 0        # the running average so far

    def add(self, value):
        self.__count += 1      
        diff = value - self.__avg  # convenience
        self.__avg += diff / self.__count

    def mean(self):
        return self.__avg

    def count(self):
        return self.__count
```

I need to add two more methods to this

1. **maximum()** which returns the maximum value ever recorded by the Statistics object and none if no values are seen.
2. **minimum()** which returns the minimum value ever recorded by the Statistics object and none if no values are seen.

I tried using max() and min() functions couldn't include them properly.
Any help where I can rectify my mistake?
Here is how that looked:

```
class Statistics(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__count = 0      # how many data values seen so far
        self.__avg = 0        # the running average so far
        self.__max= 0
        self.__max=max(value)


    def add(self, value):
        self.__count += 1      
        diff = value - self.__avg  # convenience
        self.__avg += diff / self.__count


    def mean(self):
        return self.__avg

    def count(self):
        return self.__count
        
    def maximum(self):
        return self.__max
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same thing that you do for `self.__avg` but instead for a `self.__max` / `self.__min` - keep the current max/min in a instance variable.

On adding a new value via `self.add(..)` check if the new value is bigger as your current and set your `self.__max` - do the same for minimal value.

You can init your instance variables to `None` to start with.

```
class Statistics(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__count = 0      # how many data values seen so far
        self.__avg = 0        # the running average so far
        self.__max = None
        self.__min = None


    def add(self, value):
        self.__count += 1
        diff = value - self.__avg  # convenience
        self.__avg += diff / self.__count
        
        self.__max = value if self.__max is None else max(self.__max, value)
        self.__min = value if self.__min is None else min(self.__min, value)


    def mean(self):
        return self.__avg

    def count(self):
        return self.__count
    
    def maximum(self):
        return self.__max

    def minimum(self):
        return self.__min
```

Test:

```
s = Statistics()

print(s.maximum(), s.minimum(), s.mean()) 

s.add(42)
s.add(11)
s.add(-13)
s.add(142)
s.add(99)

print(s.maximum(), s.minimum(), s.mean())
```

Output:

```
None None 0
142 -13 56.2
```

See [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator) for what `self.__max = value if self.__max is None else max(self.__max, value)` does.